# Enter Supabase URL and API Key makes the page go blank

Tags: reactjs, authentication, supabase, supabase-database

I'm trying to implement supbase authentication and the moment that I use

```
const supabase = createClient(
'URL','KEY'
);
```

after that the page just goes blank
This is my full code

```
import { createClient } from "@supabase/supabase-js";
import { Auth } from "@supabase/auth-ui-react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { ThemeSupa } from '@supabase/auth-ui-shared'
const supabase = createClient(
'URL',
'API KEY'
);

function Login() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

        supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange(async (event) =>{
            if (event!=="SIGNED_OUT"){
                //forward to success URL
                navigate("/success");
            }
            else{
                //forward to localhost:3000
                navigate("/");
            }
        })


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Auth 
            supabaseClient={supabase}
            appearance={{theme: ThemeSupa}}
            theme="dark"
            providers={["discord"]}
        
        />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

after doing diagnosis by remove all the code, I found out that the moment I enter the createClient line it makes the pages go blank

I expect the page to appear

Answer (score 0):

Is this react? If so, you want to wrap your `onAuthStateChange` callback in `useEffect` or something so that it does not run on every render

```
useEffect(() => {
  supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange(async (event) =>{
            if (event!=="SIGNED_OUT"){
                //forward to success URL
                navigate("/success");
            }
            else{
                //forward to localhost:3000
                navigate("/");
            }
        })

}, [])
```

Comment: Nope, didn't work

Comment: @AyushDesai You should see something in the console. Are there any error messages or anything there?